# loop through every x number columns of dataset as a group in R

Tags: r

I am sure this has a simple answer and I am just missing it. How do I loop through a data frame, applying the same function to every 3 columns as a group in R? I see a lot of examples on how to apply the function to every 3rd column, but that's not what I am looking for.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(a =c(1,1,1,0,0), b=c(1,1,0,0,0), c=c(1,1,1,0,0), d=c(1,1,0,0,0), e=c(1,1,1,0,0), f=c(1,1,1,0,0))
```

I want to apply a function to a, b, and c, then loop back and apply that same function to d, e, and f.

An example function of what I am trying to accomplish is to get the sum of the number of positives of each row, of every 3 columns of the data frame.

```
numpos <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  numpos[i] <- sum(df[i,1:3]==1)
}
numpos
```

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could also use `tapply` with the appropriate grouping:

```
t(tapply(unlist(df) == 1, list((col(df) - 1) %/% 3, row(df)), sum))
  0 1
1 3 3
2 3 3
3 2 2
4 0 0
5 0 0
```

How does the grouping look like?

```
list((col(df) - 1) %/% 3, row(df)) # The grouping.
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
[3,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
[4,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
[5,]    0    0    0    1    1    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5    5
```

From above, you can tell that each of the 3 columns are considered to be in their own group. Also that each row is considered to be in its own group. thus the interaction of the two creates the requiredgrouping

Comment: This is great! Thank you :-) I think this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```r
sapply(seq(1, ncol(df), by = 3),
       function(ind) sum(df[, ind + 0:2] == 1))
# [1] 8 8
```

The `seq` is finding the start-point for each "triplet" of columns. I'm assuming for this that the number of columns is a perfect multiple of 3, otherwise you'll get an error (`undefined columns selected`).

There's no need for a `for` loop along the rows, we can rely on R's vectorized operators for that.

Alternatively, in case I misinterpreted your desired output, one could use

```r
sapply(seq(1, ncol(df), by = 3),
       function(ind) rowSums(df[, ind + 0:2] == 1))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    3
# [2,]    3    3
# [3,]    2    2
# [4,]    0    0
# [5,]    0    0
```

where the first column indicates the count of `1`s in each row of the first three columns, second output column indicates the count of `1`s in each row of the second three columns.

Comment: Sorry @MrFlick, I wasn't trying to beat you to the punch.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies! @r2evans I think your second solution is what I am looking for, however, the second column in your example does not equal the correct numbers. The correct information should be 3, 3, 2, 0, 0 for both columns.

Comment: Yeah, it does really, I accidentally tried something else and then redid that code block. (I actually modified the original data to test that the values were correct ... invariant summaries need verification in my book :-). If you actually run my code on your data, you'll see that it gives what you want without change. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `split.default` with `rowSums`

```
sapply(split.default(df, as.integer(gl(ncol(df), 3, ncol(df)))), 
         function(x) rowSums(x == 1))
```